# How to conditionally replace the value from one column of a dataframe with the value of another without iterating each column?

Tags: python, pandas

given columns
street, city, state, zip and columns new_street, new_city, new_state, new_zip.

where the 'new' columns sometimes have updated data but are sometimes null.

I basically want to say

```
if df['new_street'] != null:
    df['street'] = df['new_street']
    df['city'] = df['new_city']
#etc
```

but i want it to check each row for the condition, not the series.
the way I am currently solving this problem is using apply

```
#this code block is super inefficient, there is probably
#a vectorized way to achieve this but i dont know it


def updated_street(row):
    if row['_merge'] == 'both':
        return row['Current Delivery Address']
    return row['street']
        
def updated_city(row):
    if row['_merge'] == 'both':
        return row['Current City']
    return row['city']
    
def updated_state(row):
    if row['_merge'] == 'both':
        return row['Current State']
    return row['state']
    
def updated_zip(row):
    if row['_merge'] == 'both':
        return row['Current ZIP+4']
    return row['zip']

#if we merged in new address info, replace the old with the new
df['street'] = df.apply(updated_street, axis=1)
df['city'] = df.apply(updated_city, axis=1)
df['state'] = df.apply(updated_state, axis=1)
df['zip'] = df.apply(updated_zip, axis=1)
```

but of course that rewrites every cell in each column.

Comment: Please post sample data along with your expected outcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would loop through the columns and use `np.where` and have a formatted string beginning with `new_` to deal with those dynamic `new_` columns. This solution is vectorized with `np.where()` with a total length of the loop being `2` for the two columns.

```
import numpy as np
for col in ['street', 'city']:
    df[col] = np.where(df['new_street'] != np.nan, df[f'new_{col}'], df[col])
```

output:
No output as I couldn't test. Please provide input data :)